# how to retrieve old versions of keys using spring-cloud-vault?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I'm using `spring-cloud-vault` to retrieve the versioned `kv` from the vault server. When I'm using the `environemnt.getSecret("key1")` then it returns only the latest versions of key for example `world2`. Is there any way to retrieve the old versions of secrets by specifying the version number for a given key using `spring-cloud-vault` library?

```
#vault kv put secret/my-app key1=world1
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2018-09-20T12:00:19.6136263Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          1

#vault kv put secret/my-app key1=world2
Key              Value
---              -----
created_time     2018-09-20T12:00:27.1820524Z
deletion_time    n/a
destroyed        false
version          2
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting your question here to share it with the community.

Comment: Better Cloud's vault java driver has one branch (still under development) to read versioned KVs. This is only option I see as of now.
Here is a link https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver/tree/v1_2_feature_branch

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Vault supports as of release 2.0 the versioned Key-Value API (key-value backend v2). There are two differences to the non-versioned Key-Value API (key-value backend v1):

1. The versioned Key-Value backend uses a different API. In particular, HTTP paths and the JSON payload are slightly different.
2. The versioned Key-Value backend is able to store multiple versions.

With Spring Cloud Vault, only the first aspect, differences in the API, were considered (see the [related GitHub ticket](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/209) for further details).

Spring Cloud Vault does not use the versioning aspect (i.e. reading an older secret version) but rather reads the latest secret version. I filed [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/issues/247) for using Vault's versioning features with configuration properties/the `Environment`. That ticket should be a good place to start a discussion about how such an integration could look like and how it could make the most sense.